# Polynomial expression with modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 = 0 \pmod{29}$

I converted the expression into $(1-x^7) / (1-x)$
But I couldn't find the roots.

Comment: You can look for a multiplicative generator  $\xi$ of $\Bbb F_{29}^*$ and then consider $\xi^4$, $\xi^8$, $\xi^{12}$, $\xi^{16}$, $\xi^{20}$, and $\xi^{24}$.

Comment: The roots are the elements of order $7\pmod {29}$.

Comment: So can't I get precise numbers ?

Comment: There are only $28$ residue classes!  If all else fails, just try each one.  For a more general method, look for a primitive root.  Given one of those, it's easy to get the desired list.

Comment: So the trial-error is the only way I assume ?

Comment: I provided two methods.  Trial and error was one, using a primitive root ($2$ is one) is another.

Answer (score 0):

I got $$x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x-7)(x+13)(x+9)(x+6)(x+5)(x+4).$$

Comment: What's the idea behind ?

Comment: @Ilgaz Kuscu I just took $x^7\equiv1(mod29).$

Comment: @MichealRozenberg Oh, I got that too but especially the constant values ?

Comment: @Ilgaz Kuscu By trial and error. $2$ is not valid, $3$ is not valid,..., $7$ is valid,... It's very ugly, but it gave the result.

Comment: @MichealRozenberg Thank you appreciate your time.

Comment: @Ilgaz Kuscu You are welcome!